# Can Dataflow CDC be used for initial dump too?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

Can Google Dataflow CDC be used to copy the mysql DB tables for the very first time too or is it only used for change data going forward?
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowTemplates/tree/master/v2/cdc-parent#deploying-the-connector

Comment: It is possible to migrate MySQL tDB to BigQuery, following the documentation you shared and these [general guidelines](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/data-analytics/how-to-move-data-from-mysql-to-bigquery). Although, be aware of the limitations of this process, described [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowTemplates/tree/master/v2/cdc-parent#unsupported-scenarios). Did it help you? Was it the answer you were looking for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The CDC solution you linked to includes the initial copy as part of its normal operation.  When you first start it up, it will copy the current contents of the DB first, then continue to copy any updates.